# The joint density function of X and Y is given by

Tags: probability

The joint density function of X and Y is given by
$$
f_{X,Y} (x, y) =
\begin{cases}
2 &0<x<1,0<y<1,0<x+y<1\\
0 &elsewhere
\end{cases}
$$

Without the need to calculate the integrals,

(a) Find $P (X > 1/2|Y < 1/4)$.

(b) Find $P (X > 1/2|Y = 1/4)$.

---

I need help with part b since i know that in continuous single point probability is 0 so how can i approach this problem.

Joint density is 2 when 0<x<1 and 0<y<1 and 0<x+y<1. need to find P(x>1/2|y=1/4)

my try is to find marginal pdf of y . the range of x is between 0 and 3/4. i found the marginal pdf of y to be 3/2. using it i made an integral from 1/2 to 1 to integrate 2 over 3/2 dx

Comment: shouldn't the joint density be $0\leq f_{X,Y}(x,y)\leq1$ ?

Comment: joint density is 2 when 0<x<1 and 0<y<1 and 0<x+y<1. need to find P(x>1/2|y=1/4)

Comment: Please use mathjax and also state your tries

Comment: @Derf There is no need for densities (PDFs) to be $\le 1$. The requirement is that they are measurable, $\ge0$ and of integral $1$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio that is something very new to me as my understanding is that probabilities range from 0 to 1. I understand if we are talking about kernels. I guess just something I never met in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my try is to find marginal pdf of y . the range of x is between 0 and 3/4. i found the marginal pdf of y to be 3/2.

Yes, that is the marginal pdf of $Y$ at $1/4$.

$$\begin{align} f_Y(y) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\int_{0}^{1-y} 2\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1-y\leq 1}\,\mathrm d x \\ & = 2(1-y)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}\\ f_Y(1/4) &= 3/2\end{align}$$

> using it i made an integral from 1/2 to 1 to integrate 2 over 3/2 dx

As you stated: at $y=1/4$, "**the range of x is between 0 and 3/4**"

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\gt 1/2\mid Y=1/4) &= \int_{1/2}^{3/4} \dfrac{2}{3/2}\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$